# VB.NET i want to move from signup form to registration form if user does not exist can you please help me as aim getting error

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, exception, webforms

This is the code from signup form:

```vb
        ElseIf usernameExist(UName) Then
            MsgBox("UserName already exists")
        ElseIf Not usernameExist(UName) Then
            StudentRegistration.ShowDialog()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetFocus(studentRegistration As StudentRegistration)
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub
```

This is the code from Registration Form:

```vb
  Friend Shared Sub ShowDialog()
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
  End Sub
```

Comment: A title, and some coded (badly formatted at that) does not make a question suitable for this site.  You also need to update your question with exactly what the error you are getting and where it is occurring

Comment: Reading though what you've post though, See the registration form show dialog method is explicitly throwing a Not Implemented exception.   Is that the error your seeing?

Comment: Yes that's the error I'm getting, so when I put in the username in signup form it doesnt take me to registration form and gives me this server error/Application the method of operation is not implemented.  Exception details :system.NotImplementedException.

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Friend Shared Sub ShowDialog() 
    Throw New NotImplementedException() 
End Sub
```

This is not a failure. Your program does exactly what you code. ShowDialog() throws an exception `NotImplementedException()`. Delete the `Throw` and write what the method should else do.

Comment: Didnt work still exists soon as it tries to open form to can you plz explain

Comment: You got a NotImplementedException?

Comment: Yes and its making me crazy plz help

Comment: Search for `NotImplementedException()` in your code.

Comment: Trying to move from form1 to form1 in web forms after user input the username and password want to move to registration form using vb.net if I remove show dialog to move the error disappears but it doesnt open the next form

Comment: It's not the method, which is the cause of your problem. It is the line `Throw New NotImplementedException()'. Anyway... why do you want to overwrite the method ShowDialog()? I believe that you shouldn't do that. If you have a Form and if your Form is implemented in your project, you can use the method ShowDialog() as is it. https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=windowsdesktop-6.0